# fprinf_s converts double to 0.0000

Tags: visual-c++, io, string-formatting

Lets keep it short.

I've got the following snippet of code:

```
double score = 9.987654
fopen_s(&output, "9.output.txt", "w");
fprintf_s(output, "%.4f", &score);
fclose(output);
```

It writes 0.0000 in 9.output.txt, where it should be printing 9.9876.

Any idea of where is the problem?

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks. Now I go back to coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downfall of the older C-based I/O functions is that they don't do type checking, otherwise the error would be obvious.

The `%.4f` format requires a `double` as a parameter. You've passed a *pointer* to `double` which is being misinterpreted.